# Liquibase with PostgreSQL : it does not create the function

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, liquibase, stored-functions

Liquibase on Postgresql doesn't create functio/procedure at all;
It logs correctly on databasechangelog the current changeset as "executed" but function doesn't exists.

I'm searching to create and then call a procedure to support mandatory foreign key on new field with null value;

This my included xml file with dedicated changeset:

```
<changeSet id="20190930_update_relation_001" author="bernardo">
    <sqlFile path="../script/20190930_update_script.sql" splitStatements="true"
             stripComments="true" dbms="PostgreSQL" encoding="utf8" relativeToChangelogFile="true" />
</changeSet>
<changeSet id="20190930_update_relation_002" author="bernardo">
        <sql dbms="PostgreSQL" splitStatements="true" stripComments="true">
            SELECT update_relation();
        </sql>
</changeSet>
```

and this is my plpgsql code for:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.update_relation()
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql>'
AS $BODY$
 declare
 prCrs [...]%rowtype;
 ngCrs [...]%rowtype;
 begin
    for prCrs in select [...] loop
    with row as (insert [...] RETURNING * )
    update [...] where  id = prCrs.id; --CURRENT OF prCrs;
    end loop;

    for ngCrs in select [...] loop
    with row as (insert [...] RETURNING * )
    update [...] where id = prCrs.id; --CURRENT OF ngCrs;
    end loop;
   end;$BODY$;
```

It's simple. Liquibase logs correctly on databasechangelog table, 
but function doesn't exists actually.

WHY ?

#### EDIT

even tag  -ext:createFunction- doesn't works;
I have just tried :

```
<changeSet id="20190930_update_indirizzo_relation_001" author="bernardo">
                <ext:createFunction dbms="PostgreSQL"
                                 encoding="utf8"
                                 relativeToChangelogFile="true"
                                 replaceIfExists="true"
                                 path="../script/20190930_update_indirizzo_script.sql"
                                 functionName="update_relation" />
                <!--<sqlFile path="../script/20190930_update_indirizzo_script.sql" splitStatements="false"-->
                         <!--stripComments="false" dbms="PostgreSQL" encoding="utf8" relativeToChangelogFile="true" />-->
            </changeSet>
```

No ERROR LOG, NO FUNCTION... SOB! :-(

Comment: thanks, 
I deleted the specification on the DB version, actually the query to create the procedure not cause errors if performed by any ClientSQL

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED.
with this configuration

```
    <preConditions>
        <dbms type="postgresql" />
    </preConditions>

[..............]

<changeSet id="..." author="ego">
   <sqlFile path="../script/20190930_update_indirizzo_relation_script.sql"
                         splitStatements="false"
                         stripComments="false"
                         encoding="utf8"
                         relativeToChangelogFile="true"
                         endDelimiter=";" />
</changeSet>
```

and this (important!) sql file:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_relation( )
    RETURNS void
AS $function$
 declare
 prCrs []%rowtype;
 ngCrs negozio%rowtype;
 begin
        for prCrs in select [...] loop
            with row as (insert into [...] RETURNING * )
            update [...] where id = prCrs.id;
        end loop;
        for ngCrs in select [...] loop
            with row as (insert into [...] RETURNING * )
            update [...] id = ngCrs.id;
        end loop;
    end;
    $function$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
;
```

What's changed?

- dbms type attribute is lowercase;
- no schema name in function name;
- attribute language WITHOUT apex and AFTER body ;
- $function$ as body delimenter;
- last ";" in new row.

:-( 
there are too many and too many different examples on web.
official documentation is even worse ...

now... 
now it remains for me to find out why it does not automatically execute it in the second 'changeset'

Comment: The fact that the dbms must be written in lowercase is documented in the Liquibase manual if I recall correctly. Using it on the `changeSet` directly should work as well. And the language name is an identifier so it shouldn't be quoted anyway.

Comment: maybe, now I have to check ... but in any case it is not correct that it does not raise any error in the face of a wrong definition of language